# Assets miss in Rails (also using fragment caching). No memcache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, fragment-caching

Using Rails 3.1.1 on Heroku, running with two web dynos.

I am NOT using memcache at the moment. I am [using fragment caching successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724876/cache-only-the-main-content-in-rails).

I am getting a lot of cache miss (and very, very few fresh) in my logs. It should be noted that facebox-2 (that actually gets a "cache fresh" is **outside** the cached fragment.

As you can see, the misses are not follow by a "store" so as far as I understand, they are not actually being cached:

```
cache: [GET /assets/facebox2-e2da8b69b260f5c7f70e22a7b3e6bb26.css] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/application-282064ad715b6798765bdeb777974e9b.js] miss
cache: [GET /assets/seasons/fall_top_background2.png] miss
cache: [GET /assets/tell-a-friend-afd54b062dd0d649f6595b96bf7450a2.png] miss
cache: [GET /assets/banners/annons-884c9fbe7f6805249247ef02438fca08.jpg] miss
cache: [GET /assets/admarker-c709fa0ac510720b8ffb56e3a63a8bb3.jpg] miss
cache: [GET /assets/gifts/skolett-b97b0e5b262df6e15b95470f06917758.jpg] miss
cache: [GET /assets/closelabel.png] miss
cache: [GET /assets/loading.gif] miss
```

**Production.rb**

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

I run `rake assets:precompile` in production mode successfully locally and upload it to Heroku successfully as well.

I think my issue is very closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256815/cache-miss-with-rails-3-2-and-page-caching-in-development-anyone-else) although I am running it in Production mode (shouldn't be any difference, right?).

I have experimented a little bit with Memcached but I am still a beginner on how to use it.

My personal belief is that I am trying to fetch cached images from within a cache which messes up the verification. For example, in my fragmented cache I am looking for

`banners/annons-884c9fbe7f6805249247ef02438fca08.jpg`

whereas it might be cached with another "code" like

```
banners/annons-121b1b12b12b1b1b11b1b.jpg
```

Is this correct?

To my questions:

1. Do I have the same issue as with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256815/cache-miss-with-rails-3-2-and-page-caching-in-development-anyone-else)? Is it that I am caching within a cache, so to speak?
2. Is Memcached and Rake::Cache the way to handle this? If so, I'd prefer my fragmented html-pages to be stored as files and not in the memcache (they are 1.000 x 3 Mb). How can I do that?
3. Is it correct that fragment_caching does not actually create those files on Heroku, because apps don't have write permission?
4. Is this likely to affect the performance on my app (it is quite slow)?
5. In short, what would be an easy way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I started using Memcache and this solved this problem. Why, I am not really sure, but now it works as expected (Miss Store ---> Fresh).